# Three Js not compiled initially

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular

I'm just started Three Js from a link https://threejs.org and installed everything from the Docs.

but its not working

here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the main.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

here is my file structure
[image: file structure]

and here is the output in browser
[image: output]
[image: output 2]

I user live server VS code plugin to run the files into web browser.

Need some assistance to run the files error free.

Comment: What's it got to do with angular/react?

Comment: @Pieterjan I have to use it with Angular later.

Comment: @AmanSharma do you still need to help with this?